# Substituting float with decimal causes errors

Tags: python, numpy, decimal, floating, floating-point-conversion

The program construes equations describing the concentrations of reagents in time in consecutive reactions A->B->C->...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_equation#Consecutive_reactions

The algorithm has been devised by myself and allows one to completely ignore the need to solve the differential equations to obtain the concentration functions. It makes use of the pattern that emerges when one closely examines these equations.

The code that works uses floating point numbers, but they come at a disadvantage. When the rate constants k_n for any two given n values are similar in value, the inexactness of floating point numbers kicks in and the results drown in the ocean of error amplification:

[image: graph]

I figured that substituting float() with decimal() should fix this issue, but to my dismay, the changes caused unexpected errors:

After substituting float() with decimal():

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conreact9.py", line 280, in <module>
    exec(comm)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "conreact9.py", line 256, in graphit
    p += plt.plot(t,eval(c_(i)),label= "c_" + str(i) + "(t)")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py", line 658, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert %r to Decimal" % value)
TypeError: Cannot convert array([0, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4, -0.5, -0.6, -0.7, -0
.8, -0.9, -1.0, -1.1,
       -1.2, -1.3, -1.4, -1.5, -1.6, -1.7, -1.8, -1.9, -2.0, -2.1, -2.2,
       -2.3, -2.4, -2.5, -2.6, -2.7, -2.8, -2.9, -3.0, -3.1, -3.2, -3.3,
       -3.4, -3.5, -3.6, -3.7, -3.8, -3.9, -4.0, -4.1, -4.2, -4.3, -4.4,
       -4.5, -4.6, -4.7, -4.8, -4.9], dtype=object) to Decimal
```

And this error when I substitute NumPy exp() to decimal equivalent:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conreact10.py", line 280, in <module>
    exec(comm)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "conreact10.py", line 256, in graphit
    p += plt.plot(t,eval(c_(i)),label= "c_" + str(i) + "(t)")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: exp
```

Didn't find anything using Google or official documentation on the decimal module.

Here's the untouched code for reference:

http://pastebin.com/mfuwVq7B

And here's my attempt at modifying it:

http://pastebin.com/xde4gvHu

This may as well be something very basic I'm not able to see. I'm a student at the Faculty of Chemistry and I'm a novice when it comes to programming (no previous background). Thank you very much.

Comment: Please include your code in the question; a small reproducible sample is preferred though.

Comment: The code has 279 lines, I think leaving it at Pastebin works much better than pasting the code before and after the changes I've made here. I don't think you can take out a sample of the code and expect it to work. Everything is intertwined - the user supplies the starting conditions, algorithm builds the equations and matplotlib plots them. Of course I can add the code, but that will make my initial post even lengthier.

Comment: No, your question needs to be useable and answerable without depending on external services. Pastebin.com could go down, or completely disappear, but your question here will still be answerable. That's why I ask you to make it a *reproducible sample* instead. Working out how to reproduce your problem in a short snippet will also help you figure out what is wrong yourself.

Comment: I could list the lines where the changes were made, but those can be found by looking for "float(" and "exp(" in the first version of the code.

Comment: Like I said, I don't think it is possible to cut out any part and expect it to work. That's precisely why I had to take up programming to solve this problem - supplying this amount of information (building the equations being the most taxing) manually would take days.

Comment: I appreciate that you feel that your code cannot be reduced, but I want you to *try* anyway. Solve the `float` vs. `decimal` problem, for example. Create a small sample piece of code that'll reproduce that traceback. Try and figure that sub-problem out first, ask questions about that. Etc. You will get answers *much faster* if you reduce your problem to a *much smaller* subset first.

Comment: If I understood what causes this problem, I wouldn't be here. I have no idea why introducing decimal() in place of float() does what it does. It doesn't make sense to me. I'm not experienced enough to interpret the TraceBack message. That's why I'm here.

Comment: What is happening right now is that there is *too much text* here. One simplification you could make is remove the whole `decimal()` addition. If you don't understand why something happens when you randomly replace stuff, then don't replace stuff. Figure out one thing at a time.

Comment: Not sure what addition you're talking about nor what random replacements you mean. I replaced float() with decimal.Decimal() and numpy.exp() with decimal.Decimal().exp(). Those are not random replacements by any means. Those replacements should work analogously to their predecessors. They don't and that baffles me to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the substitution of `numpy.exp()` with `Decimal.decimal.exp()`.

[The former takes an array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html) and returns an array in which *e* has been raised to each element's power:

```
>>> x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)
>>> xx = x + 1j * x[:, np.newaxis] # a + ib over complex plane
>>> out = np.exp(xx)
```

[The latter works on single numbers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.exp):

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(1).exp()
Decimal('2.718281828459045235360287471')
```

(examples taken from the pages linked above).